# Android RecyclerView List item - button not taking intent command

Tags: button, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener, listadapter

I created an adapter with strings image and button,

image and strings working perfectly on OnClickListener() Intent Command but the button is not working,

text in that button working fine, it is changing as I set, but not getting clickable.

here is my code

**Model**

public class Video_model1 {

```
int image;
String title, link;



public Video_model1(int image, String title, String link) {
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;

}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
```

}

**Adapter**

public class Video_adapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Video_adapter1.viewholder>{

```
ArrayList<Video_model1> list;
Context context;

public Video_adapter1(ArrayList<Video_model1> list, Context context) {

    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.first_pageprint, parent, false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position) {

    final Video_model1 model = list.get(position);

    holder.image.setImageResource(model.getImage());
    holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.link.setText(model.getLink());

    holder.button1.setText(model.getTitle());

    holder.button1.setFocusable(false);



    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, video_runtime_acitivty.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", model.getImage());
            intent.putExtra("title", model.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("link", model.getLink());

            intent.putExtra("button1", model.getTitle());



            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;
    TextView title, link;
    Button button1;


    public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_video_img);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_title1);
        link = itemView.findViewById(R.id.link_text2);
        button1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_video_adpt);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the button id the same as used in the layout file?

Comment: Yes. Button Id same as I used in the layout file, and as I said, "text in that button working fine, it is changing button name as I set, but not responding to the click command"